# How to maintain a constant brightness in an input image from the live video stream

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

My application is to process the incoming image input from the live video stream and detect certain objects from that. I think changes in lights are affecting my result's accuracy. So I need to fix the value of the brightness, and to do so I am using the V parameter from the SHV color model.

I am deriving a mean value of the V parameter from the input image and try to keep that value nearer to the predefined setpoint value.
I'm using the bellow mentioned python code for this process.

```
ret, frame = cap.read()
hsvImage = cvtColor(frame, COLOR_BGR2HSV)
h,s,v = split(hsvImage)
live_value = mean(v)

brightness_factor = predefined_setpoint / live_value 

hsvImage[...,2] = hsvImage[...,2] * brightness_factor

frame = cvtColor(hsvImage, COLOR_HSV2BGR)
```

From this method, I'm getting a better result.
But still, I want to verify that whether I'm applying this logic in the right way or not.

More importantly, my main concern is with the execution frequency of the code. This method is reducing the execution frequency of my python code drastically.

Is there any lightweight process or inbuilt method available to achieve the same goal?

Comment: Try scaling the RGB (without converting to HSV). The result may be good enough.

Comment: Multiplication might be faster in opencv or numpy than in python. So try `hsvImage[...,2] = cv2.multiply(hsvImage[...,2],brightness_factor)` or `hsvImage[...,2] = np.multiply(hsvImage[...,2],brightness_factor)`

Comment: cross-post: https://forum.opencv.org/t/how-to-maintain-a-constant-brightness-in-an-input-image-from-the-live-video-stream/3728 also `np.multiply` will do the same thing as the `*`-operator with a numpy array operand.